# Cloud build for deploying Gen 2 Cloud Functions: INVALID_ARGUMENT

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-build

I am looking to deploy some code to cloud functions via cloud build. Overall aim is to have a cloud function gen 2 triggered by a change in google cloud storage using eventarc.

I was able to deploy via terminal. When I applied the same arguments in my cloudbuild.yaml and looked to deploy my cloud functions via cloudbuild, I continued to get the following error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Trigger event type must be specified.
```

This is what I ran in terminal (which deploys correctly):

```
gcloud functions deploy FUNCTION_NAME\
--gen2 \
--runtime=python310 \
--region=REGION \
--source=. \
--entry-point=ENTRY_POINT_NAME \
--trigger-event-filters="type=google.cloud.storage.object.v1.finalized" \
--trigger-event-filters="bucket=BUCKET_NAME" \
--run-service-account=SERVICE_ACCOUNT \
--trigger-location=us
```

and below is what I have in cloudbuild.yaml (which raises the error listed above):

```
  - name: 'gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk'
    args:
      - gcloud
      - functions
      - deploy
      - FUNCTION_NAME
      - --gen2
      - --runtime=python310
      - --region=REGION
      - --source=.
      - --entry-point=ENTRY_POINT_NAME
      - --trigger-event-filters="type=google.cloud.storage.object.v1.finalized"
      - --trigger-event-filters="bucket=BUCKET_NAME"
      - --run-service-account=SERVICE_ACCOUNT
      - --trigger-location=us
```

My main confusion is why the behavior between the two would be different.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I ended up building a gen 2 function using cloud build by using the arguments listed [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/deploy) for gen 1. I am not sure if this is intended behaviour but the end result was what I wanted with a Gen 2 function created with an eventarc trigger from cloud storage changes. Below is the cloudbuild.yaml that I ended up using:

```
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
args:
  - functions
  - deploy
  - FUNCTION_NAME
  - --gen2
  - --runtime=python310
  - --region=REGION
  - --source=.
  - --entry-point=ENTRY_POINT_NAME
  - --trigger-event=google.storage.object.finalize
  - --trigger-resource=BUCKET_NAME
  - --run-service-account=SERVICE_ACCOUNT
  - --trigger-location=us
```

Comment: Hi, @hugo_house, Welcome! Thanks to share your solution with the community. Please, could you check you question as resolved? Congrats!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend 2 things

- Use the cloud builder `CloudSDK` instead of your current one
- Remove gcloud in your args list because it's the default entry point of your cloud builder container

```
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
    args:
      - functions
      - deploy
      - FUNCTION_NAME
      - --gen2
      - --runtime=python310
      - --region=REGION
      - --source=.
      - --entry-point=ENTRY_POINT_NAME
      - --trigger-event-filters="type=google.cloud.storage.object.v1.finalized"
      - --trigger-event-filters="bucket=BUCKET_NAME"
      - --run-service-account=SERVICE_ACCOUNT
      - --trigger-location=us
```

Comment: Hi I appreciate the response! I gave what you did a try and unfortunately still have the same error: ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Trigger event type must be specified.

Comment: I ended up using the gen 1 arguments and was successful in creating the function. Thanks for your input as I used your recommendations in the final "solution" (unsure if this is intended behavior though)

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error and instead of using 1st gen flags, I was able to deploy the function using `python39` as runtime environment. Please try below:

```
- name: 'gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk'
  args:
    - gcloud
    - functions
    - deploy
    - FUNCTION_NAME
    - --gen2
    - --runtime=python39
    - --region=REGION
    - --source=.
    - --entry-point=ENTRY_POINT_NAME
    - --trigger-event-filters="type=google.cloud.storage.object.v1.finalized"
    - --trigger-event-filters="bucket=BUCKET_NAME"
    - --run-service-account=SERVICE_ACCOUNT
    - --trigger-location=us
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you described.

It seem to be a bug with the "args array style"

I was able to deploy gen2 function by using entrypoint bash and breakout syntax.

Test this

```
  - name: 'gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk'
    entrypoint: 'bash'
    args:
      - "-c"
      - |
        gcloud functions deploy FUNCTION_NAME \
        --gen2 \
        --runtime=python310 \
        --region=REGION \
        --source=. \
        --entry-point=ENTRY_POINT_NAME  \
        --trigger-event-filters="type=google.cloud.storage.object.v1.finalized" \
        --trigger-event-filters="bucket=BUCKET_NAME" \
        --run-service-account=SERVICE_ACCOUNT \
        --trigger-location=us
```